# ActiveRecord has_many and belongs_to implementations for foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to understand the syntax/motivation behind the input options hash in has_many and belongs_to associations. (question at the bottom)

Say I have two tables, users and posts.
a user has many posts, and a post belongs to a user. From what I understand one would set up associations like this:

**(in User model)**

```
has_many(:posts,
    primary_key: :id,
    foreign_key: :user_id, #this makes me think SQL is querying
                           #User.user_id, an invalid field
    class_name: "Post")
```

**(in Post model)**

```
belongs_to(:user,
    primary_key: :id,
    foreign_key: :user_id, 
    class_name: "User")
```

**My question(s) is(are) as follows:** 
How can I intuitively understand why the functions belongs_to and has_many are implemented this way? i.e. why wouldn't one expect the foreign_key to change when changing which association you are defining? Because, naively, I would expect the associations to be defined with different foreign keys, depending on which table your query is originating in (namely the class_name table). Is this simply a matter of convention?

I have looked at the docs for has_many/belongs_to and I think I understand how they are implemented, but I still do not understand /why/ it is implemented like that. I feel like maintaining a constant foreign key, independent of which table you are querying, obfuscates what is happening on the SQL level. (but I am hoping I am just missing something dumb)

**edit:** 
for clarity, this is the association set up which I naively thought made more sense:

**in User model**

```
has_many(:posts,
    primary_key: :user_id, #because querying post table so treat this column
                          #as a primary key

    foreign_key: :id,      #because users is the 'secondary' table,  
                          #:id should be foreign
    class_name: "Post"
)
```

**in Post model**

```
belongs_to(:user,
    primary_key: :id, #because querying User table, treat this as the
                     #primary key

    foreign_key: :user_id,  #because posts is the 'secondary' table we are 
                            #comparing to, :user_id should be foreign
    class_name: "User")
```

Answer (score 0):

Heh, I realized shortly after posting what my issue was (and it was definitely silly):
I was thinking of primary/foreign as stating which table was being queried and which was being joined respectively. When, in reality, I should have been thinking about it as which key is *truly* primary and foreign w.r.t. the database. I am doubting this will help anyone, but will leave it up just in case as it gave me a headache (even though it probably shouldn't have).